# Cannot work out how a property accessor is called by using the keyword "this"

Tags: c#

Thanks in advance guys. I am quite new to coding so please be patient. Below is a piece of code I am working on. This is the complete code below. It's as follows:

```
using System;

public class Product
{

    private string name;
    private decimal price;


    public string Name
    {
        get
        { return name; }
        set
        { name = value; }
    }

    public decimal Price
    {
        get
        { return price; }
        set
        { price = value; }
    }



    public Product(string name, decimal price)
    {

        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

In the page load method, an object is instantiated and the constructor is called as follows:

```
 private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        Product saleProduct = new Product("Kitchen Garbage", 49.99M);

    }
```

When the product is created, the constructor is initialised, with the above values. Now if you look in the constructor, you have:

```
this.name = name;
```

and

```
this.price = price;
```

After the above two lines of code are executed, the property accessors automatically assign the private variables ("name" and "price") with the intended values.

So how are the lines:

```
this.name = name;
```

and

```
this.price = price;
```

able to call the public accessors, named "Name" and "Price"?

I have only seen when a public accessor is explicitly called such as:

```
saleProduct.Name = "Kitchen Garbage";
```

I don't understand how:

```
this.name = name;
```

and

```
this.price = price;
```

can access a private variable directly. I thought the whole point of property accessors was that you had to go via the property name in order to access the private variables such as:

```
saleProduct.Name = "Kitchen Garbage";
```

Can you help and explain how

```
this.name = name;
```

and

```
this.price = price;
```

is able to access the public properties? Even the name of the properties ie "Name" and "Price" are changed  to "Kitchen Garbage" and "49.99" respectively when the above two lines of code are executed.

Also, how does

```
this.name = name;
```

and

```
this.price = price;
```

know which public accessor to call?

I have searched everywhere for an explanation but no luck.

Thank you.

Comment: `I have searched everywhere` doubtful: [this (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx)

Comment: they aren't calling the public accessor.

Answer (score 3):

The private members `name` and `price` are accessible in all non-static methods within the class `Product`.  Since the constructor for `Product` is part of the class, the members are accessible there as well.

Your constructor is not using the public properties `Name` and `Price`.  They retrieve their values from the corresponding private members.

Comment: @FredBurnett because `Name` pulls from `name`, when you set `name` = "whatever", `Name` now returns a value of "whatever"

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you. But one thing, when I step through the code using debug, as soon as the line,  this.name  =  name;  is executed,  the property, "Name" also takes on the new value assigned to "name". So if as you said, the constructor is not using the public properties Name and Price, then why do their values also change to the values supplied in the constructor, and why is the property "Name" and "Price" affected? Sorry if this question is basic.

Comment: Thank you Brendan, very much appreciated.

Comment: @FredBurnett the public properties are like "nicknames" for your private members.  You could call them `Thing1` and `Thing2` and they would still update, because they pull directly from the private members.  As soon as you update the members, the public properties pull those updated values too.  Just think of them as a public "alias" or "nickname" that is exposing those private values, rather than as separate containers.

Answer (score 1):

`this.name` refers to `private string name;`. It's private, so only code inside the class can refer to it.

The `this.` prefix is only required because otherwise the code would be ambiguous, since there's a parameter called `name` as well.

The public accessor `public string Name` does not have any storage of its own. It passes through to the private field `name`.

The code `this.name = name;` does not touch the property `Name` - it's the other way around.

When you do `this.name = name;`, you are setting the value of the private field called `name`.

Whenever you access the public property `Name`, you are indirectly accessing that same field (`name`).

Look at the definition of the property:

```
get { return name; }
```

Note that here, `name` refers to the same field as `this.name`. You could change it to `this.name` and there'd be no effect. It's just not required here, since there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

in your constructor you are not setting the values via the public setter, you're setting the private backing field directly.

FYI I believe it is generally considered best practice to name class level items with an Upper letter (or underscore sometimes in the case of members/backing fields?), and function level variables and parameters with a lower letter. (Don't quote me on this paragraph :P)

so to set the field via it's setter just do:

```
public class Foo
{
    private string _bar;
    public string Bar
    {
        set
        {
            this._bar = value;
        }    
        get
        {
            return _bar;
        }
    }

    public Foo(string bar)
    {
        this.Bar = bar;
    }
}
```

vs.

```
public Foo(string bar)
{
    this._bar = bar
}
```

The above is equivalent to what you're doing in your code.  Note with your current implementation it doesn't *really* make a difference, since you have no additional logic in your setter.  If you did however, in your implementation you would miss out on that additional logic.
note i changed the variables around a bit to make it more obvious what's being done.

to demonstrate that point consider this:

```
public class Foo

    private string _bar;
    public string Bar
    {
        set
        {
            this._bar = value + " blah blah";
        }    
        get
        {
            return _bar;
        }
    }

    public Foo()
    {
        this.Bar = "test";
        Console.WriteLine(Bar); // outputs "test blah blah"

        this._bar = "test";
        Console.WriteLine(Bar); // outputs "test"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.name = name;
```

and

```
this.price = price;
```

are used in the Constructor for the Product class.  Private members are accessible from the Constructor (as well as from any non-static method on the class).

Basically, when you 'new' an object, the memory structure of the object is allocated, and then the constructor is called to allow for any initialization of that object.  Making the name and price member variables private just means that you can only access them from inside the class members themselves, of which the constructor is.

The public properties Name and Price, as implemented here, are just wrappers around those private name and price variables, and allow you to do other things when setting or fetching (imagine wanting to count the number of times a value is referenced:  you could increment some counter in the get{} of a public property).

Comment: Thanks Chris. I understand this. In my code, when I use debug to step through the code, when I execute the line, this.name  = name; The "Name" property also changes to the same value as this.name. I am slightly confused as to how this.name = name; automatically changes the value of the property "Name" as there is no obvious connection.

Comment: Right, that's because Name is defined to just return this.name in your get{} method.  Think of the get{} and set{} methods for the public property Name as just methods on the object... since get{} for Name is defined to just return this.name, any modification of this.name in that object will changes what the get{} method returns.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining this Chris. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The lower cased `name` and `price` are private 'backing' variables for the public `Name` and `Price` variables. They can only be accessed from within the class itself. The reason for using `this.price` is because the method is taking a param called 'price' so you need to specify that you're setting the classes field and not assigning to the local variable. You'll often see this in constructors, personally I would choose to name the arguments something different than the fields in my class and then it wouldn't be necessary.